# Add base uri to a smart contract that splat other collection

Tags: solidity

HI i want to clone the smart contract from splat by devotion,the contract use a function to splat any nft collection ,so i try to add my BaseUri using the format IpFs://..but i cant see the image,also when i try to splat the image i cant add any other collection than the one in the smart contract .if u can help me with how to add the image before mint,the splat image and to use any collection like in this original smart contract .here is the code and the contract address 0x61db2f3b0584324793a48800e8b54aea714da934
Thanks everyone

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
//pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import { ERC721A } from "erc721a/contracts/ERC721A.sol";
import { Ownable } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import { ERC165Checker } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/ERC165Checker.sol";



contract Splat is ERC721A, Ownable {


  mapping(address => bool) public addressHasMinted;

  // Tracks the SplatId to the URI
  mapping(uint => string) public transformations;

  // Contract address -> token id -> bool
  mapping(address => mapping(uint => bool)) public addressTokenSplatted;

  bytes4 private ERC721InterfaceId = 0x80ac58cd;
  bytes4 private ERC1155MetadataInterfaceId = 0x0e89341c;

  uint public price = 0.05 ether;
  uint public splatCount;
  uint public constant MAX_SUPPLY = 1000;

  string public _baseTokenURI;

  bool mintEnabled;
  bool splatEnabled;

  address public withdrawAddress = 0xEf5C1d031F3b71c15f6DD7b2078a54c6f866DDBf;

  // Errors

  error AlreadyMinted();
  error AlreadySplatted();
  error MintClosed();
  error MintedOut();
  error NoContracts();
  error MuseumSecurity();
  error WrongPrice();

  // Events

  event Setter(uint indexed splatId, address indexed usingContractNFT, uint indexed tokenId);

  // Constructor

  constructor() ERC721A("Splat by Devotion", "SPLAT") {
    _mint(msg.sender, 1);
  }

  // Mint

  function mint() external payable {
    if (msg.sender != tx.origin) revert NoContracts();
    if (mintEnabled == false) revert MintClosed();
    if (totalSupply() + 1 > MAX_SUPPLY) revert MintedOut();
    if (addressHasMinted[msg.sender]) revert AlreadyMinted();
    if (msg.value != price) revert WrongPrice();

    addressHasMinted[msg.sender] = true;

    _mint(msg.sender, 1);
  }

  function hasTokenBeenSplatted(address _contractAddress, uint _tokenId) view public returns (bool){
    return addressTokenSplatted[_contractAddress][_tokenId];
  }

  // Once you splat, you can't splat that piece again
  function splat(uint splatId, address usingContractNFT, uint usingTokenId) external {
    // Security is everywhere, no splatting...yet.
    if (splatEnabled == false) revert MuseumSecurity();

    // Prevents a token from being re-splatted
    if (hasTokenBeenSplatted(usingContractNFT, usingTokenId)) revert AlreadySplatted();

    require(ownerOf(splatId) == msg.sender, "Not your Splat");

    // ERC-721 check
    if (ERC165Checker.supportsInterface(usingContractNFT, ERC721InterfaceId)) {
      (bool success, bytes memory bytesUri) = usingContractNFT.call(
        abi.encodeWithSignature("tokenURI(uint256)", usingTokenId)
      );

      require(success, "Error getting tokenURI data");

      string memory uri = abi.decode(bytesUri, (string));

      transformations[splatId] = uri;
      addressTokenSplatted[usingContractNFT][usingTokenId] = true;
      unchecked { ++splatCount; }

      emit Setter(splatId, usingContractNFT, usingTokenId);

    // ERC-1155
    } else if (ERC165Checker.supportsInterface(usingContractNFT,ERC1155MetadataInterfaceId)) {
      (bool success, bytes memory bytesUri) = usingContractNFT.call(
        abi.encodeWithSignature("uri(uint256)", usingTokenId)
      );

      require(success, "Error getting URI data");
      string memory uri = abi.decode(bytesUri, (string));

      transformations[splatId] = uri;
      addressTokenSplatted[usingContractNFT][usingTokenId] = true;
      unchecked { ++splatCount; }

      emit Setter(splatId, usingContractNFT, usingTokenId);

    // Punks
    } else if (usingContractNFT == 0xb47e3cd837dDF8e4c57F05d70Ab865de6e193BBB) {
      string memory uri = string.concat('punk ', toString(usingTokenId));

      transformations[splatId] = uri;
      addressTokenSplatted[usingContractNFT][usingTokenId] = true;
      unchecked { ++splatCount; }

      emit Setter(splatId, usingContractNFT, usingTokenId);

    } else {
      revert("Not an ERC-721 or ERC-1155");
    }
  }

  // Plucked from OpenZeppelin's Strings.sol
  function toString(uint value) internal pure returns (string memory) {
    // Inspired by OraclizeAPI's implementation - MIT licence
    // https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/b42146b063c7d6ee1358846c198246239e9360e8/oraclizeAPI_0.4.25.sol

    if (value == 0) {
        return "0";
    }
    uint temp = value;
    uint digits;
    while (temp != 0) {
        digits++;
        temp /= 10;
    }
    bytes memory buffer = new bytes(digits);
    while (value != 0) {
        digits -= 1;
        buffer[digits] = bytes1(uint8(48 + uint256(value % 10)));
        value /= 10;
    }
    return string(buffer);
  }

  function promoMint(address _to, uint _count) external onlyOwner {
    if (totalSupply() + _count > MAX_SUPPLY) revert MintedOut();
    _mint(_to, _count);
  }

  function _startTokenId() internal view virtual override returns (uint) {
    return 1;
  }

  // Setters

  function setBaseURI(string calldata _baseURI) external onlyOwner {
    _baseTokenURI = _baseURI;
  }

  function setMintOpen(bool _val) external onlyOwner {
    mintEnabled = _val;
  }

  function setSplatOpen(bool _val) external onlyOwner {
    splatEnabled = _val;
  }

  function setPrice(uint _wei) external onlyOwner {
    price = _wei;
  }

  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return _baseTokenURI;
  }

  // Withdraw

  function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
    (bool sent, ) = payable(withdrawAddress).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    require(sent, "Withdraw failed");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am Aleksa from Upwork.
I checked the smart contract again (https://etherscan.io/address/0x30535831e3244dc15153ce173c2803af4ee7e374#readContract) and understood the whole process.
Regarding SPLAT NFT, they used backend server to adjust metadata of NFT and in result you tried to change baseURI, but it didn't work.
Let's keep in touch to continue the work.